# OpenForms won't run when I open a new form twice

Tags: c#

I've run into some problems when opening a new form. The first time the new form is opened the code runs as expected, but if I close that form and open a new one right after, the code has a problem executing correctly.

Observe that this is not the main form, this is a separate form that is opened from the main form.

I suspect the problem is lying in the Application.OpenForms that I'm running from a separate class. But I really can't figure out why it wouldn't run the second time.

Here is an example (this code runs from a separate class.):

In the textbox (txtCFProjectNr) I wrote "0000-0000", it returns 0000-0000 the first time the form is opened, the second time it returns "2".

```
    static frmCFNewProject newProjFrm = Application.OpenForms.OfType<frmCFNewProject>().FirstOrDefault();

    public static void projectNrChanged()
    {
        bool format = Regex.IsMatch(newProjFrm.txtCFProjectNr.Text, @"[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]");
    }
```

Here is how I open the new form

```
    public void btnCFCreateNewStructure_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmCFNewProject frm = new frmCFNewProject();
        frm.ShowDialog();
    }
```

When I restart the application, it works like a charm, until the form is closed and opened again.

I hope this explains enough. 
I apologize for my bad English, this is not my native language. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: I suggest you call `Application.OpenForms.OfType<frmCFNewProject>().FirstOrDefault();` **when you want to use it** rather than having it as a `static` field.

Comment: What you should be doing, is creating the form when you need it and then throw it out; this would negate the issue's you are somewhat already seeing. Currently you are creating a single field that is shared among all objects created from a single class, don't do this.

Comment: `shared among all objects created from a single class, don't do this`, in this case you don't need to I should've said... Also you shouldn't be doing a static routine that accesses the UI field, static routines should be state-less; in your case that could be `public void projectNrChanged`...

Comment: Thanks guys! I've used the static field in my previous apps and it has worked out well in the past. Anyway from now on I'll use only when I need it! Much apriciated! Thanks again!